# XHR error (404 Not Found) in angular2/http

Tags: angular

Downloaded Quickstarter project for Angular2, did not do any change and ran `npm start` and got the following errors:

```
localhost/:16 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic//bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js(…)(anonymous function) @ 

system.src.js:373 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:373
VM54:3 GET http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQpQtkZ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSEDscheduleTask @ zone.js@0.6.12:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js@0.6.12:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js@0.6.12:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js@0.6.12:122send @ VM54:3Request.create @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Request @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1XHR.request @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1XHR.doPoll @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Polling.poll @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Polling.doOpen @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Transport.open @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Socket.open @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Socket @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Socket @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:1Manager.open.Manager.connect @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:2(anonymous function) @ browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js:3ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js@0.6.12:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js@0.6.12:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12:423
```

I am really frustrated for the above errors, please help if somebody had solved it earlier.

Comment: Which Quickstart project for Angular2 (link)?  Did it provide instructions on how to install and run it?  The error says you don't have the node module for for angular2 (@angular) installed.  Do you have Node installed?  If so, did you do npm --install in the project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [Quickstart Github Repo](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) to clone angular 2. Just did, and it's working fine.
Your issue is due to the strucrure change in new angular 2 rc.

Additionally, update your node and then npm install again.

Bharat.

Comment: Thanks Bharat , in my case after trying a lot of other things lastly adding http as devDependencies worked. I don't know why it is not mentioned in tutorial that we will need to install http as devdependencies.